# ActiveRecord rollback and return RecordInvalid message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to save multiple objects, and rollback all if any of them fail. But I also want to render the ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid message so the user knows why it didn't save. How do I do this?

```
def save_multiple_things_or_error
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    thing_one.save!
    thing_two.save!
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => exception
    # exception.message is what I want to render
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
  end
end
```

This doesn't work for a few reasons. I believe the rescue should be in a begin end block, but then if I raise the rollback, I lose the RecordInvalid exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try this one:

```
begin
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
   thing_one.save!
   thing_two.save!
  end
rescue => e 
  raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
end
```

this works fine for my situation

Comment: Does the raise ActiveRecord::Rollback need to be in the transaction do block?

Comment: not for me. in my case, i need to catch all exceptions (i had an seeding with seedfiles, so i got the same behavior like the migrations) if one seedfile failes (not exist, typo e.g.) , i want to rollback the complete action.

Comment: Can you please edit this answer to indicate where I would render the RecordInvalid exception message?